# libgit2sharp - how to undo the change in working copy only?

Tags: libgit2sharp

Given a file a.txt that exists in the repository already, we do the following operations - modify-stage-modify(again).

How do I undo the change of the working copy (essentially revert it to staged version)?

I tried Repository.CheckoutPaths(), but it undid both working copy and staged copy.

Thanks,

Ning

Comment: The question is essentially how to achieve "git checkout -- filepath" with libgit2sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specifiy the filepath?

```cs
using(var repo = new Repository("path"))
{
   var opt = new CheckoutOptions();
   repo.CheckoutPaths(repo.Head.Tip.Id.Sha, new string[] { "filepath" }, opt); 
}
```

where `filepath` is the path to `a.txt`